# numpy.memap, Pandas dataframe and seaborn boxplot Troubles

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, seaborn, memory-mapped-files

I'm running an analysis over several large datasets (in total much bigger than my RAM).
To facilitate my work, I load the datasets using `numpy.memmap` (after having saved them to individual .npy files generated from tomographic datasets).

After extracting several values from the datasets I collect these values in a Pandas dataframe.
The values show up nicely when I look at them (for example via `df.head()`).

I would now like to visualize the values with something like `seaborn.boxplot(data=df, x='Treatment', y='Tumor_Vol', hue='Experiment_Day')`, but I get the error that

```
ValueError: List of boxplot statistics and `positions` values must have same the length
```

It seems to me that this is due to the memory-mapped values, since the exact same command works when I save the dataframe to a CSV file and load it back from disk (which is my current workaround).

So---for lack of better words---is there a way I can un-memorymap values and save them as 'real' values to a dataframe?

Comment: You can just call `copy` on the subset of the data that you're interested in to pull it into ram. e.g. `data_subset = memmap_data[i:j].copy()`

Comment: Doesn't seem to help, with `plot_copy = df.ix[:, ['Tumor_vol', 'Experiment_Day', 'Treatment']].copy()` I still get type `<class 'numpy.core.memmap.memmap'>` for i in plot_copy['Tumor_vol'].

Comment: If you include a minimum, complete, verifiable example (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I might be able to hack something together. Otherwise it's kind of hard to piece together what you're trying and what's not working.

Comment: I agree that it's super-hard without an incomplete example. I'll see if I can trim the problem down to a complete example on Monday.

Comment: Funnily, the problem does *not* show up when I try to recreate it: https://gist.github.com/habi/4af9a2c2369348072a08a31f01cc135a
The gist contains a trimmed down copy of the original notebook showing the error and my attempt on recreating it...

Answer (score 0):

I have been running into the same kind of very weird bug. This shows up only on a jupyter notebook though.

I have a simple dataframe which is plotted okay with swarmplot but not with boxplot (on a notebook but the same code works on the terminal). It very weird because some other dataframe are plotted fine with the same code.

My dataframe:

```
    sample  color   right-left  (right-left)/right
0   OPAR19_r1c3     Blue    1   0.000334448
1   OPAR19_r1c3     Green   305     0.255444
2   OPAR19_r1c3     Red     15  0.0205479
3   OPAR19_r2c6     Blue    82  0.028063
4   OPAR19_r2c6     Green   260     0.216847
5   OPAR19_r2c6     Red     14  0.0183246
6   OPAR19_r1c1     Blue    75  0.0251931
7   OPAR19_r1c1     Green   -13     -0.0143488
8   OPAR19_r1c1     Red     10  0.0137741
9   OPAR19_r1c4     Blue    -38     -0.0131579
10  OPAR19_r1c4     Green   117     0.110169
11  OPAR19_r1c4     Red     0   0
12  OPAR19_r1c6     Blue    7   0.00239153
13  OPAR19_r1c6     Green   -3  -0.00295858
14  OPAR19_r1c6     Red     -46     -0.0640669
15  OPAR19_r2c4     Blue    95  0.0315824
16  OPAR19_r2c4     Green   191     0.163668
17  OPAR19_r2c4     Red     36  0.0447761
18  OPAR19_r2c5     Blue    48  0.0164215
19  OPAR19_r2c5     Green   165     0.154639
20  OPAR19_r2c5     Red     -4  -0.00542005
21  OPAR19_r1c5     Blue    199     0.0655468
22  OPAR19_r1c5     Green   262     0.223169
23  OPAR19_r1c5     Red     103     0.141678
24  OPAR19_r1c2     Blue    102     0.0340681
25  OPAR19_r1c2     Green   198     0.179837
26  OPAR19_r1c2     Red     75  0.0955414
27  OPAR19_r2c1     Blue    221     0.0742857
28  OPAR19_r2c1     Green   99  0.108791
29  OPAR19_r2c1     Red     11  0.0147453
30  OPAR19_r2c2     Blue    159     0.0526664
31  OPAR19_r2c2     Green   64  0.0724802
32  OPAR19_r2c2     Red     -21     -0.0276316
33  OPAR19_r2c3     Blue    16  0.00536733
34  OPAR19_r2c3     Green   84  0.0769936
35  OPAR19_r2c3     Red     -49     -0.0639687
```

This plot fails on the notebook but not on a python file

```
sns.boxplot(data=df_out2,x='color',y='right-left')
```

here is the error:

```
ValueError: List of boxplot statistics and `positions` values must have same the length
```

While the equivalent plot with swarmplot or stripplot works fine:

```
sns.swarmplot(data=df_out2,x='color',y='right-left')
```

Comment: I actually realized this as nothing to do with being run on the notebook or on the terminal. I just run this on the terminal by loading the data from a csv file. So if my dataframe is saved to a csv and then reloaded, the error does not show up. So it means this is related with the dataframe, but I don't know what's wrong

Comment: Same issue here.  Any solutions?